# Multi-level MVC Routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a special need.  I have an application with five modules:-

1. Membership
2. Rental
3. Administration
4. Accounting
5. Reports

I am developing the application using MVC.  I would like to have different type of Routing for this application as follows:-

```
/Module/Page/Action
```

Examples are:-

```
/Membership
/Membership/Home/
/Accounting
/Accounting/Home/
/Membership/Membership/Edit/1
/Accounting/JournalVoucher/Delete/1
```

etc.

Please note, that the Home page is repeated for every module.

I nearly have around 70 screens in my application. Can you please tell me what is the best way to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any complication here.
Since you didnt mention any language or framework that you are using, lets say you are using PHP/CodeIgniter.

```
/Membership
/Membership/Home/
/Accounting
/Accounting/Home/
/Membership/Membership/Edit/1
/Accounting/JournalVoucher/Delete/1
```

To handle these URLs, you simply create 2 controllers -

```
membership_controller
function Home

accounting_controller
function home
function membership($action, $param)
function journalvoucher($action, $param)
```

Regarding the structure you mentioned -

```
/Module/Page/Action
```

For every module, create a controller.
For every page, create a function.
Pass the actions as parameters to the function.

In case you have a variable number of parameters, then let the second parameter be an array.

Comment: .. or maybe you could assume, that he/she is not using a framework , which uses a mis-implemented MVC as marketing pitch.

Comment: mis-implemented MVC ? I'd call it flexibility and thats what I love most about CI :-) But yes I agree, I should have picked a stricter MVC as an example in the answer !

Comment: Well .. any framework which points you to an ORM instance and say: *"see, this is model"* is a pile of dren. I kinda have [strong opinions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5864000/727208) about mvc.